# ¿Cómo enviar parametros a un openquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de leer la variable @NAME en la consulta pero me aparece un error de sintaxis.

```
DECLARE @NAME AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @NAME = 'Jhon Smith'

select * 
from openquery(
    DATA_BASE, 
    'select * from where code = 'ADM-0001' and name = '+@NAME+' order by (id) desc')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```sql
    DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @NAME  VARCHAR(100)
    SELECT  @NAME = 'Jhon Smith'
    SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,''SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = ''''' + @NAME + ''''''')'
    EXEC (@TSQL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener mucho cuidado al ejecutar cadenas con valores concatenados. Es el primer paso para sufrir de inyección de SQL. Aquí dejo un ejemplo de como hacer la consulta de una forma más segura pero que tiene la limitante de que el parámetro no puede ser mayor a 128 caracteres.

```
DECLARE @NAME AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @NAME = 'Jhon Smith'

DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) 
SET @SQL = REPLACE( N'
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY ([172.18.2.115], N''SELECT * 
                                FROM MiTabla 
                                WHERE name = ''<<uservalue>>'' 
                                ORDER BY id DESC;'');',  '<<uservalue>>', QUOTENAME(@NAME, ''''));

PRINT @SQL;
EXEC (@SQL);
```